# Python better way to breakpoint?

Tags: python

right now i use

```
    foo()
import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
bar()
```

for debugging purposes. Its a tad cumbersome, is there a better way to implement a breakpoint in python?

edit: i understand there are IDE's that are useful, but i want to do this programatically, furthermore all the documentation i can find is for `pdb.set_trace()` instead of `breakpoint()` i would appriciate an explanation on how to use it

Comment: `breakpoint()` from python 3.7+

Comment: I prefer to use an editor where I can visually set a break point and step through my code.

Comment: Get a decent IDE like Eclipse or IntelliJ/PieCharm.

Comment: If you plan on doing any heavy lifting in python, idle is not the way to do it. You need to get an ide where you do like @Code-Apprentice mentioned. That will give you full debugging tools

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally I prefer to use my editor for debugging. I can visually set break points and use keyboard shortcuts to step through my code and evaluate variables and expressions. Visual Studio Code, Eclipse and PyCharm are all popular choices.

If you insist on using the command line, you can use the interactive debugger. See the [pdb documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pdb.html) for details.

Answer (score 0):

Python 3.7 added a [breakpoint() function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#breakpoint) that, by default, performs the same job without the explicit import (to keep it lower overhead). It's [quite configurable](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.7.html#whatsnew37-pep553) though, so you can have it do other things.